# quarto preview gives a slightly different website than github pages

Tags: r, github-pages, quarto

I have this R package hosted on github. https://github.com/daniellga/rdocs

If I run `quarto preview _docs`:

[image]

Now if I go to the github pages website generated in https://daniellga.github.io/rdocs/:

[image]

Why are they different and how to make them the same as the first one?